# need to replace map with variable value

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have xslt and below code works fine, however I need to replace "map{"abc": "yes","dDEF": "Yes","RMT": "dsfdf","PPAS": "Yes","UNITE": "Yes"}"  with variable

```
<xsl:variable name="var_res">
        <xsl:value-of select='map:for-each(map{"abc": "yes","dDEF": "Yes","RMT": "dsfdf","PPAS": "Yes","UNITE": "Yes"}, function($k, $v){ 
          {
            if($v!="Yes" and $v!="No")
            then $k else ""})' />             
        </xsl:variable>
```

as below :

```
        <xsl:variable name="var_mapValue" >
            <xsl:value-of select="/root/input/collective_barg"></xsl:value-of>
            
        </xsl:variable>



      <xsl:variable name="var_res">
        <xsl:value-of select='map:for-each(map(var_mapValue)}, function($k, $v){ 
          {
            if($v!="Yes" and $v!="No")
            then $k else ""})' />             
        </xsl:variable>
```

map(var_mapValue) doesn't work not sure what is missing here

and my input xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<input>
<collective_barg>
{"abc": "yes","dDEF": "Yes","RMT": "dsfdf","PPAS": "Yes","UNITE": 
"Yes"}
</collective_barg>
</input>
</root>
```

Comment: XSLT 2 doesn't have those maps or `map:for-each`, either you are using XSLT 3 or I am missing some context. If you want us to help to convert the XML in `/root/input/collective_barg` into a map of string keys to string values you will need to show a relevant XML sample and explain which values in the XML you want to use as keys and which ones as values.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response . yes I am using XSLT 3 and my input example is    
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
<collective_barg>
{"abc": "yes","dDEF": "Yes","RMT": "dsfdf","PPAS": "Yes","UNITE": "Yes"}
</collective_barg>
</input>

Comment: Edit your question and show and explain the input as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

To parse the JSON and turn it into what the XML Data Model defines as a "map", you should use the XPath 3.1 function `parse-json()` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-json

```xml
<xsl:variable name="map" select="parse-json(/root/input/collective_barg)"/>
```

Also NB string comparison in XSLT is case sensitive; the string value `Yes` is not equal to `yes`. I suggest you use the `upper-case()` (or `lower-case()`) function to normalize the text and then compare it to `"YES"` (or `"yes"`).

By the way, when you are declaring a variable, you can just assign its value using the `select` attribute; you don't need to enclose an `xsl:value-of` element. Using `xsl:value-of` just has the effect of converting the data to a string. If you really do want to convert it to  a string, you can use the `string()` function. e.g. don't do this:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="var">
        <xsl:value-of select="blah"/>         
        </xsl:variable>
```

do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="blah"/>
```

or if you do want to convert the input to a string, do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="string(blah)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

mange to fix the issue by using ParseJson

```
    <xsl:variable name="var_mapValue" >
          <xsl:value-of select="Parse-json(/root/input/collective_barg)"> 
  </xsl:value-of>
        
    </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="var_res">
    <xsl:value-of select='map:for-each($var_mapValue, function($k, $v){ 
      {
        if($v!="Yes" and $v!="No")
        then $k else ""})' />             
    </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: The function's name is `parse-json`, not `Parse-json`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72806503/need-to-replace-map-with-variable-value/72833311#answer-72809683).

Comment: By the way, I went to look at your previous questions because I thought this question seemed familiar and I noticed you don't seem to accept any of the answers to your questions. Please, if an answer is correct and helpful, accept it! This is so that other users who face the same issue in future can then see that there's a solution.